# ¿Multiplicar datos almacenados en array por aparte en python?

Tags: python, numpy

Buen día, ¿me podrían sacar de una duda?

Estoy tratando de multiplicar tres arreglos, pero quiero que al momento de efectuarse la operación, los valores se muestren por separado.

```
E=float(input("Ingrese el módulo elástico"))
E=np.array(E)
...
L=np.diff(X)
...
I=float(input("Ingrese momento de inercia"))
I=np.array(I)

# RIGIDEZ (K) DE CADA ELEMENTO:
K=(12*E*I)/L
```

El problema radica en `K` ya que debería haber dos valores por separado; pero me los muestra todo en uno.

> ([array([ 40528.,121584.])], [array([ 40528., 121584.])])

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que los valores me salgan por separado para manejar dos matrices diferentes? Además, ¿me pueden indicar qué error estoy cometiendo para que me imprima `array`?

¡¡Gracias!!

Comment: Para que podamos ayudarte mejor deberías dejar el código completo para que podamos ejecutarlo y probarlo (No en una imagen) además de la respuesta que obtienes y la respuesta que quieres obtener.

Comment: @fg94 el código completo no es buena idea. Es mejor pedir un [emcv](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: use np.nditer(), ¿Podría dar un ejemplo del patrón de salida que necesita?

Comment: Hola!!, te recomiendo dar un vistaso a la función *hsplit* o *vsplit*, puedes checar la documentación oficial aquí [hsplit](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hsplit.html). Estas funciones separan un arreglo de numpy, ya sea vertical u horizontalmente.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con

```
for value in K:
  print(value)
```

Si no, puedes probar igual pero poniendo `print(value.tolist())`.